# Materialized view with FAST refresh on remote table: How to include a SHAPE column?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, integration, sdo-geometry

I want to create an Oracle materialized view with the **fast refresh** option on a **remote table** (in an enterprise GDB).

I can do this successfully *without* a  SHAPE column:

```
create materialized view log on maximo.workorder with primary key;  --remote table
grant select maximo.mlog$_workorder to schema_for_dblink; --I've provided a dblink access to everything in a certain schema

create materialized view my_gis_schema.wo_mv --enterprise GDB
build immediate 
refresh fast
start with sysdate next sysdate + (15/(60*60*24))
as
select
    cast(workorderid as number(38,0)) as objectid, --workorderid is a fake primary key; it has a NOT NULL constraint and a unique index
    wonum,
    status,
    --other fields
    longitudex,
    latitudey
from
    maximo.workorder@my_dblink
```

---

The MV above works, but I want to store the XY coordinates from the remote table in a **SHAPE** column in the MV.

Unfortunately, my options seem pretty limited:

1. Oracle doesn’t seem to support SDE.ST_GEOMETRY in MVs (more info [here](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1067173_1.html) and [here](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009568)).

   - Although, I didn’t get that far — due to the fact that the schema I was using (SYSTEM) to create the MV  doesn’t have the “inherit privileges” for the SDE owner (more info [here](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012391) and at the bottom [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/privileges-oracle.htm)). I assumed, even if I sorted out the SDE privileges issue, I still wouldn't be able to proceed, due to the limitations in #1.
   - The SQL would be: `sde.st_geometry(longitudex,latitudey,null,null, 26917 ) as shape`
2. Additionally, Oracle doesn't seem to support SDO_GEOMETRY in MVs on a **remote table** with the **fast refresh** option: `ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query`

   - The SQL would be: `sdo_geometry(2001, 26917, sdo_point_type(longitudex,latitudey, null), null, null) as shape`

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to include a SHAPE column in a materialized view  in a **remote table** with the **fast refresh** option?

Answer (score 2):

I have a few options. I can create the fast refresh MV on a remote table ***without*** the SHAPE column, but then add the SHAPE column afterwards.

---

### **A. Add SDO_GEOM column & trigger**

Create an SDO_GEOMETRY column in the MV after-the-fact:

```
alter table my_gis_schema.wo_mv add shape mdsys.sdo_geometry;
```

---

And add a trigger in the MV to populate the column:

```
create or replace trigger my_gis_schema.wo_mv_sdo_geom_shape
    before insert or update
    on my_gis_schema.wo_mv
    for each row
declare
    v_longitudex number (16,2);
    v_latitudey  number (16,2);
    v_plussisgis number (1,0);
begin
    v_longitudex  := :new.longitudex;
    v_latitudey   := :new.latitudey;
    v_plussisgis  := :new.plussisgis;
    if v_plussisgis = 1 then
        :new.shape := mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001, 26917, mdsys.sdo_point_type(v_longitudex, v_latitudey, null), null,null);
    end if;
end;
```

---

Refresh the data in the MV so the that SHAPE column gets populated for existing rows (via the trigger).

```
exec dbms_mview.refresh('WO_MV', 'C');
```

The 'C' parameter stands for 'COMPLETE'.

---

Create a spatial index on the MV. This can be done with SQL or with the *Add Spatial Index* geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Desktop.

---

Note: In my case, I also created a query layer on top of the MV so that I could exclude non-spatial records:

```
select
    *
from
    my_gis_schema.wo_mv
where
    plussisgis = 1
```

---

### **B. View on top of MV**

Create a view on top of the materialized view that generates the SHAPE column on-the-fly:

```
create or replace view wo_mv_vw as (
select
    objectid
    wonum,
    status,
    --other fields
    longitudex,
    latitudey,
    sdo_geometry(2001, 26917, sdo_point_type(longitudex,latitudey, null), null, null) as shape
from
    my_gis_schema.wo_mv
)
```

Notes:

1. The dynamic SDO_GEOMETRY column performs surprisingly well (almost indistinguishable from a static field in a table).
2. If I were to create a dynamic SDE.ST_GEOMETRY column instead, it wouldn't perform nearly as well (10x slower). I'm not sure why.

---

### **C. View with function-based spatial index**

Create a view on the MV with a SHAPE column (just like with option B), but improve performance by using a [function-based spatial index](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-objects-function-based-indexes.htm).

---

Create a deterministic function:

(edit: it turns it’s [not necessary to create a custom function.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381872/135445))

```
create or replace function sdo_geom_from_xy(longitudex in number, latitudey in number)
return sdo_geometry deterministic is
begin
    --I'm not sure how to handle XYs that are NULL. The function-based index seems to error out when there are NULLs. For now, I'm returning zeros instead of nulls -- until I understand a bit more about what is going on.
    return sdo_geometry(2001, 26917, sdo_point_type(nvl(longitudex,0), nvl(latitudey,0), null),null, null);
end;
```

---

Update USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA:

```
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata values(
    'WO_MV',
    --no spaces allowed: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/geometry-metadata-views.htm#SPATL546
    'my_gis_schema.sdo_geom_from_xy(longitudex,latitudey)',
    sdo_dim_array(
        sdo_dim_element('X', 663795.93, 676674.94, 0.001),  --note to self: check if these coordinates are right.
        sdo_dim_element('Y', 4857659, 4879068.83, 0.001)), 26917);
```

---

Create a function-based spatial index:

```
create index wo_mv_idx on 
    wo_mv(my_gis_schema.sdo_geom_from_xy(longitudex,latitudey))
    indextype is mdsys.spatial_index;
```

---

Create a view that uses the the function-based spatial index:

```
create or replace view wo_mv_vw as (
select
    objectid
    wonum,
    status,
    --other fields
    longitudex,
    latitudey,
    my_gis_schema.sdo_geom_from_xy(longitudex,latitudey)) as shape
from
    my_gis_schema.wo_mv
)
```

Notes:

- The performance will be better than a view without a function-based spatial index. (The performance should be as good as the MV that has a static SHAPE column.)
- I haven’t tried creating a function-based index on a view with an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY column. Edit: [I'm not sure if that's possible or not.](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-ideas/st-geometry-function-based-spatial-indexes/idi-p/1172462/jump-to/first-unread-message)
- The view must use the **exact same syntax** that was used in the
  function-based index. In this case, it's this:
  `my_gis_schema.sdo_geom_from_xy(longitudex,latitudey))`.
- There is a related post here: [Can I create an Oracle Spatial View from a non-spatial table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92554/can-i-create-an-oracle-spatial-view-from-a-non-spatial-table/92599#92599) (with an excellent answer from @AlberGodfrind.

---

### **D. Additional local MV with SDO_GEOM column**

As mentioned, it's **not** possible to have a SHAPE column in a fast MV on a **remote table**.

But we ***can*** create an additional MV that would reference a so-called "local table" -- aka the MV from option A. In the additional MV, we could add a SHAPE column.

That would allow us to avoid the fast refresh/remote-table/MV error: `ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query`

### **E. Add SDE.ST_GEOMETRY column & trigger**

Just like option A, where we added an SDO_GEOMETRY column to the MV, we could alternatively add an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY column:

```
alter table my_gis_schema.wo_mv drop column shape;
alter table my_gis_schema.wo_mv add shape sde.st_geometry
```

---

And add a trigger in the MV to populate the SDE.ST_GEOMETRY SHAPE column:

```
create or replace trigger wo_mv_st_geometry_shape
    before insert or update
    on my_gis_schema.wo_mv
    for each row
declare
    v_longitudex number (16,2);
    v_latitudey  number (16,2);
    v_plussisgis number (1,0);
begin
    v_longitudex  := :new.longitudex;
    v_latitudey   := :new.latitudey;
    v_plussisgis  := :new.plussisgis;
    if v_plussisgis = 1 then
        :new.shape := sde.st_geometry(v_longitudex,v_latitudey,null,null,26917);
    end if;
end;
```

---

Refresh the data in the MV so the that SHAPE column gets populated for existing rows (via the trigger).

```
exec dbms_mview.refresh('WO_MV', 'C');
```

---

Create a spatial index on the MV. This can be done with the *Add Spatial Index* geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Desktop.

Note: SDE.ST_GEOMETRY performs slightly slower than SDO_GEOMETRY (points draw slightly slower in map).

### **F. Temporarily convert to binary (or WKT)**

For scenarios where there is an existing ST_GEOMETRY or SDO_GEOMETRY SHAPE column in the source data:

It might be possible to do the following (untested):

1. Convert the shape column [to binary](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-asbinary.htm) ([or even WKT](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-astext.htm))
2. Store the data in the MV using a datatype that MVs support
3. Add a SHAPE column to the MV after-the-fact
4. Add a spatial index to the SHAPE column
5. Create a trigger that un-converts the binary [back to a SHAPE value](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-geomfromwkb.htm) and store it in the SHAPE column.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague has suggested that it's possible to solve this issue by:

> *"...creating a public synonym in the target DB on the top of DB link; the remote table will act like local table."*

Supposedly, the synonym solves the issue of creating a materialized view with FAST refresh on a **remote table** with an SDO_GEOMETRY column.

```
CREATE public SYNONYM maximo.workorder FOR maximo.workorder@my_dblink;

-- ... then create the materialized view.
```

My colleague says it has been tested and it works; it was tested using a [fake primary key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280839/why-am-i-able-to-create-mv-logs-using-pk-even-though-there-is-no-pk), which is consistent with my setup.

Unfortunately, I haven't had a chance to test it myself. I don't have CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW privileges at the moment, so I haven't been able to verify if it works or not.

Answer (score -1):

Option-B in your answers i would suggest to go with.
However I have another Option thinking of is to create a STORED PROCEDURE instead of Materialized View. The procedure which will update the ESRI Geodatabase Feature class table as ST Geometry. That should make the ArcGIS configuration convenient.

Answer (score -1):

Creation of MV including the shape column would cause issue if the table is having geometry column as ST_Geometry.
This is a know issue
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009568

Answer (score -1):

If the feature class is registered as versioned, creating the materialized view from  the EVW view including the st_geometry shape column would be helpful.