# Function-based spatial index: Use sdo_geometry() constructor instead of custom function?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, spatial-index, function, sdo-geometry

I have an Oracle 18c table that has XY columns, but not a SHAPE column. I've created a query on the table that **dynamically** generates an sdo_geometry SHAPE column.

```
sdo_geometry(2001, 26917, sdo_point_type(longitudex,latitudey, null), null, null) as shape
```

---

**Function-based spatial index:**

In an effort to improve the performance of the query, I've created a function-based spatial index.

The [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-objects-function-based-indexes.htm#SPATL799) provide instructions for creating a **custom function** for the purpose of the function-based index. So that's what I've done:

```
--Create a deterministic function:
create or replace function sdo_geom_from_xy(longitudex in number, latitudey in number)
return sdo_geometry deterministic is
begin
    return sdo_geometry(2001, 26917, sdo_point_type(nvl(longitudex,0), nvl(latitudey,0), null),null, null);
end;

--Update USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA:
delete from user_sdo_geom_metadata where table_name = 'WO_MV2_SBX';
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata values(
    'WO_MV2_SBX',
    'maximo.sdo_geom_from_xy(longitudex,latitudey)',
    sdo_dim_array(
        sdo_dim_element('X', 663795.93, 676674.94, 0.001),  --note to self: these coordinates are wrong.
        sdo_dim_element('Y', 4857659, 4879068.83, 0.001)), 26917);

--Create a function-based spatial index:
drop index wo_mv2_sbx_idx;
create index wo_mv2_sbx_idx on 
    wo_mv2_sbx(maximo.sdo_geom_from_xy(longitudex,latitudey))
    indextype is mdsys.spatial_index;

--Create a view that uses the the function-based spatial index:
create or replace view wo_mv2_view_sbx as (
select
    objectid,
    maximo.sdo_geom_from_xy(longitudex,latitudey) as shape    
from
    maximo.wo_mv2_sbx
where
    plussisgis = 1
);
--Note: In order for the view get the benefit the function based index, the view *MUST* use the exact same syntax that was used in the function-based index.
```

---

**Question:**

When I use the custom function, everything works as expected. However, it seems strange to me that I would need to create a custom function, when the out-of-box sdo_geometry() constructor would do what I want.

Is there a way to use the sdo_geometry() constructor in a function-based index instead of custom function?

**Edit:**

There is a related post here:

[Can I create an Oracle Spatial View from a non-spatial table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92554/can-i-create-an-oracle-spatial-view-from-a-non-spatial-table/92599#92599) (with an excellent answer from @AlberGodfrind.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, despite what the Oracle docs imply, we **can** use the sdo_geometry() constructor instead of a custom function.

```
--Update USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA:
delete from user_sdo_geom_metadata where table_name = 'WO_MV2_SBX';        
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata values(
    'WO_MV2_SBX',
    --I'm using decode() to handle NULL XY values (via my plussisgis flag/column)
    'decode(plussisgis,1,mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(longitudex,latitudey,null),null,null))',
    sdo_dim_array(
        sdo_dim_element('X', 663795.93, 676674.94, 0.001),  --note to self: these coordinates are wrong.
        sdo_dim_element('Y', 4857659, 4879068.83, 0.001)), 26917);

--Create a function-based spatial index:
drop index wo_mv2_sbx_idx;    
create index wo_mv2_sbx_idx on 
    wo_mv2_sbx(decode(plussisgis,1,mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(longitudex,latitudey,null),null,null)))
    indextype is mdsys.spatial_index;

--Create a view that uses the the function-based spatial index:
create or replace view wo_mv2_view_sbx as (
select
    objectid,
    decode(plussisgis,1,mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(longitudex,latitudey,null),null,null)) as shape    
from
    maximo.wo_mv2_sbx
where
    plussisgis = 1
)
--Note: In order for the view get the benefit the function based index, the view *MUST* use the exact same syntax that was used in the function-based index.
```

So that helps simplify things; no need for a custom function.

---

More info here:

[Function for a function-based spatial index: if X not null and Y not null (can't contain spaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65320558/function-for-a-function-based-spatial-index-if-x-not-null-and-y-not-null-cant)

[Function: if either x or y are null, return null](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281702/function-if-either-x-or-y-are-null-return-null)