# Equivalent to USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA for SDE.ST_GEOMETRY

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, oracle-dbms, st-geometry

Background - SDO_GEOMETRY:

If I were to create a function-based spatial index that returns an SDO_GEOMETRY, I would manually insert records into SDO_GEOMETRY's `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` for these purposes:

1. To register the indexed ***function***, similar to what's done for SDO_GEOMETRY columns in ***tables***.
2. Register a ***view*** that uses the indexed geometry column — so that GIS software knows that the index should be used for the view (to boost performance when displaying the view/features in the map).

- An answer from @AlbertGodfrind on [function-based spatial indexes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92554/create-an-sdo-geometry-view-from-a-non-spatial-table/92599#92599)
- Oracle docs: [10.2 SDO_GEOMETRY Objects in Function-Based Indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/extending-spatial-indexing.html#GUID-CFB6B6DB-4B97-43D1-86A1-21C1BA853089)

---

Question - SDE.ST_GEOMETRY:

I want to create a function-based spatial index on an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY function (not an SDO_GEOMETRY function).

In a quick test, I was able to successfully create a function-based spatial index that returns an ST_GEOMETRY:

```
CREATE INDEX atn_startpoint_shape ON infrastr.active_transportation 
    (sde.st_geomfromwkb(sde.st_asbinary(sde.st_startpoint(sde.st_geometryn(shape,1))),300125)) 
         INDEXTYPE IS SDE.ST_SPATIAL_INDEX parameters ('ST_GRIDS=320 ST_SRID=300125');
--                             ↑↑↑


Index ATN_STARTPOINT_SHAPE created.
```

But it seems to me that a piece is still missing: the equivalent of registering the index (and a view) with a table like `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA`.

---

Is there an equivalent to `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` for SDE.ST_GEOMETRY?

Related idea: [ST_Geometry: Function-based spatial indexes](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-ideas/st-geometry-function-based-spatial-indexes/idc-p/1172537)

Comment: Apples and oranges -- there is no equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

**Index SQL Hint:**

I don't think an index hint is an *equivalent* mechanism, but maybe it's what's done for ST_GEOMETRY instead, since we don't use `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` for ST_GEOMETRY:

> An Oracle hint provides directive to the optimizer in choosing an
> execution plan for the SQL statement being executed.
>
> The Oracle INDEX hint instructs the optimizer to use an index scan for
> the specified table. Use the INDEX hint for function-based, domain,
> B-tree, bitmap, and bitmap join indexes.
>
> When working with tables containing **ST_Geometry** attributes and a
> st_spatial_index, specify the **Oracle INDEX hint** and the name of
> the st_spatial_index to instruct the optimizer to access the data by
> way of the index.
>
> As stated in Oracle's SQL Reference documentation, ('If the INDEX hint
> specifies a single available index, then the database performs a scan
> on this index. The optimizer does not consider a full table scan or a
> scan of another index on the table.') when an INDEX hint is specified
> the optimizer uses the index as the primary access path.
>
> Esri Technical Article: [How To: Set a SQL hint to instruct the Oracle optimizer in choosing an execution plan](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009658)